# Need iptables to forward a couple ports to another local port

Tags: iptables, wireguard

I’m running Wireguard and want it to listen to more ports than the default. The easiest way since it´s managed by Algo, seems to be to forward the ports using iptables, but i can’t make it work.

Here is what i tried so far:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 46.101.***.***/32 -p udp -m multiport --dports 53,80,443,554 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 51819

iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 554 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 554 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Last two commands repeated for every port. The ip 46.101.***.*** is the ip of my eth0 interface where the service is running. I can only connect on udp:51819 no other port. There is no other firewall active.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this did the trick

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 80,443,554,51819 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -m multiport --dports 80,443,554 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 51819
```